# Is there a way to partially match a text/string and return it's full value in R

Tags: r

I am having a data frame and I need to fill some columns based on values matched in another column.

Run this code to give you sample dataset

```r
sample_data <- structure(list(Temp = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), Wind = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), NodeID = c(3, 5, 
6, 8, 9), node_path = c("Temp <= 82 , Wind <= 6.9", "Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp <= 77", 
"Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp > 77", "Temp > 82 , Wind <= 10.3", 
"Temp > 82 , Wind > 10.3")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I am trying to achieve. Match column names `Temp` and `Wind` along the `node_path` and return the specific matched values to these columns. I have tried using `str_extract_all(node_path, pattern = "^Temp.*")`, but this returns the whole cell values under `node_path`. Any idea how I could achieve this?

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option (without reshaping) is to extract the elements based on the column name (`cur_column()`) by looping `across` the 'Temp', 'Wind' NA columns and `paste` (`toString`) the `list` elements from `str_extract_all` by looping over the `list` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
sample_data %>% 
    mutate(across(c(Temp, Wind), ~ map_chr(str_extract_all(node_path, 
         str_c(cur_column(), "\\D+[0-9.]+")), toString)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Temp                   Wind         NodeID node_path                           
  <chr>                  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                               
1 Temp <= 82             Wind <= 6.9       3 Temp <= 82 , Wind <= 6.9            
2 Temp <= 82, Temp <= 77 Wind > 6.9        5 Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp <= 77
3 Temp <= 82, Temp > 77  Wind > 6.9        6 Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp > 77 
4 Temp > 82              Wind <= 10.3      8 Temp > 82 , Wind <= 10.3            
5 Temp > 82              Wind > 10.3       9 Temp > 82 , Wind > 10.3
```

---

Or the same logic can be used in `base R` with `regmatches/regexpr` to extract the values based on the pattern and then `paste` with `toString`

```
sample_data[1:2] <- lapply(names(sample_data)[1:2], function(x) 
      sapply(regmatches(sample_data$node_path, gregexpr(paste0(x, 
    "\\D+[0-9.]+"), sample_data$node_path)), toString))
```

---

Or another option is using `separate_rows` to split the rows, then do a `pivot_wider` to reshape back to wide format

```
library(tidyr)
sample_data %>% 
    select(node_path, NodeID) %>%
    separate_rows(node_path, sep="\\s*,\\s*") %>% 
    mutate(colnm = word(node_path, 1)) %>%
    group_by(colnm, NodeID) %>% 
    summarise(new = str_c(node_path, collapse=", "), .groups = 'drop') %>%  
    pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = new) %>%    
    left_join(sample_data %>% 
                 select(NodeID, node_path))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  NodeID Temp                   Wind         node_path                           
   <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>        <chr>                               
1      3 Temp <= 82             Wind <= 6.9  Temp <= 82 , Wind <= 6.9            
2      5 Temp <= 82, Temp <= 77 Wind > 6.9   Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp <= 77
3      6 Temp <= 82, Temp > 77  Wind > 6.9   Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp > 77 
4      8 Temp > 82              Wind <= 10.3 Temp > 82 , Wind <= 10.3            
5      9 Temp > 82              Wind > 10.3  Temp > 82 , Wind > 10.3
```

Comment: I tried my best to avoid using `separate_rows` and use `separate` instead to differentiate it than your last solution, but I got difficulty setting the number of `into` cols as sometimes they are 3 and sometimes 2.

Comment: Yes, with `separate`, we need to provide the column names of a particular length.  With `cSplit`, it does automatically and fill those columns having less number of elements in each row with NA

Answer (score 1):

This solution can also be used, however the very best ones have already been presented:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

sample_data %>%
  mutate(pmap_dfr(select(cur_data(), node_path), ~ {x <- c(...)
  x %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    separate_rows(value, sep = "\\s\\,\\s") %>%
    group_by(grp = str_sub(value, 1, 4)) %>% 
    summarise(conc = paste(value, collapse = ", ")) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = conc)}))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Temp                   Wind         NodeID node_path                           
  <chr>                  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                               
1 Temp <= 82             Wind <= 6.9       3 Temp <= 82 , Wind <= 6.9            
2 Temp <= 82, Temp <= 77 Wind > 6.9        5 Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp <= 77
3 Temp <= 82, Temp > 77  Wind > 6.9        6 Temp <= 82 , Wind > 6.9 , Temp > 77 
4 Temp > 82              Wind <= 10.3      8 Temp > 82 , Wind <= 10.3            
5 Temp > 82              Wind > 10.3       9 Temp > 82 , Wind > 10.3
```